# How do I debug the Eclipse CDT's Regex Error Parser?

Tags: regex, eclipse, parsing, eclipse-cdt

I've wrote up my regex for error parsing of an unsupported compiler. However, it seems to ignore me and I don't know how to debug it.

The error message looks like this:

```
"file.c", line 224: Error:  #20: identifier "myvar" is undefined
```

I wrote up this regex for Error:

```
"(.*?)", line (\d+): Error: #(\d+): (.*)
File: $1, Line: $2, Desc: $4
```

Eclipse's Console and Problems tabs seems to ignore it. What am I missing here?

*Eclipse for Windows 3.7.1, CDT 8.0.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my regex wasn't matching the error message.

The following regex solved the issue:

```
"(.*?)", line (\d+): Error:(\s*)#(.*): (.*)
File: $1, Line: $2, Desc: $5
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: while I use [an online Javascript-based regex tester](http://www.regextester.com/),
to debug CDT regular expressions I prefer to click into the console and use the regular search dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone. I was trying to get a custom parser working but I could never get it to match. It was a setup problem. You have to setup the match in Window > Preferences > c/c++ > Build > Settings > Error Parsers. To get it to USE it you have to check it in  > Properties > c/c++ build > settings > error parsers.

Answer (score 0):

It did help me, actually. In response to your question about how to debug the error parser, I did my regex pattern testing with Python against strings captured from a compiler run. Once I got that working I just pasted the regexes into the error parser form in CDT.

Obviously, there are many different ways to play with regex, notably Perl.

Comment: This is not an answer, You should read the FAQ. Stack overflow is a bit different from a simple forum. What you posted would be better as a comment rather than an answer.